# Trigger not firing in production but does in non-production

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a trigger that is firing with out issue in non-production but the same exact code is failing to fire in production. I've confirmed it's not disabled and I've done a trace to see that it is not even executing in production.. I've checked the relevant `OBJECTPROPERTY` elements and they are the same. I've confirm the code is the same. I've confirmed the same inserts are coming from the application. Below is the code for this trigger:

```
/****** 
  Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tr_trigger_ins]    
  Script Date: 06/02/2012 16:51:51 
******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_trigger_ins] ON [dbo].[table_1]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE table_2
    SET col_1 =
      CASE 
        WHEN i.col_2 = '0' THEN 0 ELSE 1
      END
  FROM INSERTED i
  INNER JOIN table_3 pa 
    ON i.col_3 = pa.col_3 AND pa.col_4 = 'ispublic'
  INNER JOIN table_4 pp  
    ON i.col_5 = pp.col_5
  INNER JOIN table_2 cs
    ON pp.col_6 = cs.col_6
END
GO
```

Below is a trigger that is an instead of insert on the same table that is executing in both environments:

```
/****** 
  Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tr_trigger_before_ins]    
  Script Date: 06/02/2012 16:55:52 
******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_trigger_before_ins] ON [dbo].[table_1]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_1
    SELECT * FROM INSERTED
    WHERE col_3 in (73, 199)
END
GO
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same inserts"? Does that mean that exactly the same data are being inserted? I mean, your `INSTEAD OF` trigger has a condition for `col_3`. Have you verified that the rows being inserted match the condition?

Comment: I have confirmed the rows match the condition being done and I don't have any the same data being inserted but this second trigger prevent data from coming in the doesn't match the criteria

Comment: Did you check if recursive triggers are allowed on database level? I didn't try, but it seems logical to me that instead-of trigger would only allow after trigger to run if recursive triggers option is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately it came down to the issue of replication.  Transactions flowed over in a different order than expected.  Once we accommodated for this in the trigger logic it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the trigger hasn't been disabled:

```
ENABLE Trigger tr_trigger_ins ON dbo.table_1;
GO
```